# Is this the correct way to implement scaled printing in Cocoa?

Tags: cocoa

I am trying to implement printing in my new Cocoa application. Everything has been working fine for a while except for scaling, i.e. printing at 75%, 125%, etc.

As far as I can tell from the Apple docs, the program supposed to adjust the rectangle returned from the rectForPage: method depending on the scale factor. I found some sample Apple code that appeared to work this way, and an old post on cocoabuilder.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Printing/osxp_pagination/osxp_pagination.html

http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/211683-scaled-printing.html

My rectForPage: code looked like this:

```
NSPrintInfo *pi = [[NSPrintOperation currentOperation] printInfo];
NSSize paperSize = [pi paperSize]; // Calculate the page dimensions in points
// Convert dimensions to the scaled view
CGFloat pageScale = [[[pi dictionary] objectForKey:NSPrintScalingFactor] floatValue];
CGFloat topMargin = [pi topMargin];
CGFloat leftMargin = [pi leftMargin];
CGFloat bottomMargin = [pi bottomMargin];
CGFloat rightMargin = [pi rightMargin];
CGFloat pageHeight = (paperSize.height - topMargin - bottomMargin) / pageScale;
CGFloat pageWidth = (paperSize.width - leftMargin - rightMargin) / pageScale;
NSRect bounds = [self bounds];
NSRect actualPageRect = NSMakeRect(
                                   NSMinX(bounds),
                                   NSMinY(bounds),
                                   pageWidth * pageScale,
                                   pageHeight * pageScale);

return actualPageRect;
```

However, I couldn't get that to work correctly. No matter what size rectangle this method returned, the output was always printed at 100%. I did verify that actualPageRect would vary based on the scale setting, and the printed output would crop to the specified rectangle, but it would not scale. I was kind of expecting that Apple would scale the view based on the scale factor, but it did not.

After long investigation, I gave up on that tack, and tried another approach. Now I have rectForPage: always return the actual page size, and I changed drawRect: to draw scaled output with an affine transformation:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    [super drawRect:dirtyRect];
    NSAffineTransform* xform = [NSAffineTransform transform];
    [xform scaleXBy:pageScale yBy:pageScale];
    [xform concat];
    [self layoutReport];
    [xform invert];
    [xform concat];
}
```

I also modified the knowsPageRange: method to take the scaling into account.

The upshot is -- this works. The program now produces whatever scaled output I want, and it is paginated correctly. But I'm pretty sure this is the wrong solution. I think there must be some detail I'm missing that would allow it to scale properly by scaling the rectangle returned from rectForPage:, but I am stumped at this point. Since it's working, I could just leave it, but if this is not the correct method I would prefer to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start with the definition of `rectForPage:`, from [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsview/1483252-rectforpage?language=objc):

> Implemented by subclasses to determine the portion of the view to be printed for the page number `page`.

and

> A rectangle defining the region of the view to be printed for `pageNumber`. This method returns `NSZeroRect` if `pageNumber` is outside the view’s bounds.

So these are crop rectangles. Whatever you draw gets cropped to this rect, and that drawing is taken as the content of that page. (You *might* also get that rectangle back in `drawRect:` with the expectation that you'll skip drawing anything outside of it.) These rectangles are in both bounds units (i.e., the same units that `self.bounds` is in) and real-world units (defaulting to 1/72 inch).

So, what about the `scalingFactor` of the print info?

As far as I can tell, as of 10.12.6, it is not applied for you by AppKit—you have to retrieve and use the `scalingFactor` yourself. (I could be missing something.)

Scaling your drawing in `drawRect:` is a totally reasonable way to do that. Your page rect will remain unchanged; your drawing within it will be scaled. If the `scalingFactor` is 2, your drawing will be doubled and you'll have a quarter of it (1/2 on each axis) within the page rect.

Since page rectangles are in bounds units, scaling the bounds (with `setBoundsSize:` or `scaleUnitSquareToSize:`) is the other way. Then both your drawing *and* the page rect will scale in unison. The catch is that this applies to both screen drawing and print drawing; it makes the most sense when you have a separate view or view hierarchy for printing.

So, based on the reference documentation (and my experimentation on 10.12.6), I think you have it right.

As for the example in the docs, I think it's written for something like TextEdit's page view where the margins are part of the view's drawing (note that it crops off `topMargin` and `bottomMargin`, for example). That said, I would recommend that you [file a bug](https://bugreport.apple.com/) anytime you find example code that seems wrong, unclear, or built on unstated assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

my two cents for OSX / Swift 5:
(dont miss knowsPageRange, or rectForPage will not be called.)

```
override func knowsPageRange(_ range: NSRangePointer) -> Bool {
        return true
    }


override func rectForPage(_ page: Int) -> NSRect {

    guard let pi = NSPrintOperation.current?.printInfo else{return CGRect.zero}

    let paperSize = pi.paperSize // Calculate the page dimensions in points
    // Convert dimensions to the scaled view

    let dict = pi.dictionary()
    let pageScale = dict[NSPrintInfo.AttributeKey.scalingFactor] as! CGFloat

    let topMargin = pi.topMargin
    let  leftMargin = pi.leftMargin
    let bottomMargin = pi.bottomMargin
    let rightMargin = pi.rightMargin
    let pageHeight = (paperSize.height - topMargin - bottomMargin) / pageScale
    let pageWidth = (paperSize.width - leftMargin - rightMargin) / pageScale
    let bounds = self.bounds
    let actualPageRect = NSRect(x: NSMinX(bounds), y:  NSMinY(bounds), width: pageWidth * pageScale, height: pageHeight * pageScale)

    return actualPageRect
}
```

be sure to have some case where you answer with a zero Rect, so printing will stop: otherwise You will print indefinitely.

in my case I simply did:
..

```
if page>1{return CGRect.zero}
```